# How to update a row if textbox value matches with a cell value in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a simple program, don't know any complex VBA code, just doing simple experiment.

In this file everything is going well but when I am trying to update any row, it's just writing values to the next line but I want code to update the same line in which slip number I entered in the Slip number field in user-form.

[image]

```
    Private Sub cmdupd_Click()
  'Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  'Dim a As Long
  'Dim rng_dest As Range

  i = 1
  Do Until Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("B" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("B" & i).Value = Vehicle_In.txtsr.Value Then

        Exit Sub
      Else
        Exit Do

    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop

    On Error GoTo ErrOccured
    'Boolean Value
    BlnVal = 0
    
    'Data Validation
    Call Data_Validation
    
    'Check validation of all fields are completed are not
    If BlnVal = 0 Then Exit Sub
      
    'TurnOff screen updating
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
     
    'Variable declaration
    Dim txtRolLNumber, txtname, txtvehicle, cmdtyre, txtmobile, txtcompany, txtdate, txttime, txtadvance, datetime
    Dim iCnt As Integer
    
    'find next available row to update data in the data worksheet
    iCnt = fn_LastRow(Sheets("VEHICLE IN")) + 1

    'Update userform data to the Data Worksheet
    With Sheets("VEHICLE IN")
        .Cells(iCnt, 1) = iCnt - 1
        .Cells(iCnt, 2) = Vehicle_In.txtsr
        .Cells(iCnt, 3) = Vehicle_In.txtvehicle
        .Cells(iCnt, 4) = Vehicle_In.cmdtyre.Value
        .Cells(iCnt, 5) = Vehicle_In.txtname
        .Cells(iCnt, 6) = Vehicle_In.txtmobile
        .Cells(iCnt, 7) = Vehicle_In.txtcompany
        .Cells(iCnt, 8) = Vehicle_In.txtdate
        .Cells(iCnt, 9) = Vehicle_In.txttime
        .Cells(iCnt, 10) = Vehicle_In.txtadvance
        .Cells(iCnt, 11) = Vehicle_In.datetime
      
        
        'Diplay headers on the first row of Data Worksheet
        If .Range("A1") = "" Then
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Sr. No"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Slip No"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Vehicle Number"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "Vehicle Tyre"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "Driver's Name"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "Contact Number"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "Company"
            .Cells(1, 8) = "In Date"
            .Cells(1, 9) = "In Time"
            .Cells(1, 10) = "Advance Paid"
            .Cells(1, 11) = "Date & Time"
            
            'Formatiing Data
            .Columns("A:K").Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1:K1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A1:K1").LineStyle = xlDash
            
        End If
    End With
    
    'Display next available Id number on the Userform
    'Variable declaration
    Dim IdVal As Integer
    
    'Finding last row in the Data Sheet
    IdVal = fn_LastRow(Sheets("VEHICLE IN"))
    
    'Update next available id on the userform
    Vehicle_In.txtRolLNumber = IdVal
    'Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("a1").Value + 1
Call Clear_Field

Me.cmdupd.Visible = False
Me.cmdsave.Visible = True

cmdtyre.SetFocus

ErrOccured:
    'TurnOn screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question. Instead include only the relevant parts of the code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review and update the initial part of your code.

```
   i = 1
   Do Until Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("B" & i).Value = ""
      If Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("B" & i).Value = Vehicle_In.txtsr.Value Then
          Exit Do
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Loop
```

This portion of the code is not getting used later when updating the data. As @braX has noted, please remove the code link and post the code written under Save button as that is where you need the updates.